# Style to dynamically created elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to do something like this:

Suppose before the page is loaded, the structure of page is like this:

```
<div class="maindiv">
<div><a href="www.google.com" class="divlink">div1</a></div>
<div><a href="www.google.com" class="divlink">div2</a></div>
<div><a href="www.google.com" class="divlink">div3</a></div>
<a class="showmore" onclick="somefunctiontoloadmoreitems()">showmore</a>
</div>
```

Now I am using jQuery and overriding the `href` of the links like this

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('.divlink').attr('href','www.facebook.com');
});
```

So after the loading, the page the will be like this.

```
<div class="maindiv">
<div><a href="www.facebook.com" class="divlink">div1</a></div>
<div><a href="www.facebook.com" class="divlink">div2</a></div>
<div><a href="www.facebook.com" class="divlink">div3</a></div>
<a class="showmore" onclick="somefunctiontoloadmoreitems()">showmore</a>
</div>
```

It's OK till now.

Now when someone will click on the showmore link, the next three items will be appended to maindiv. This link will be deleted and a new showmore link will be created after the all six `div`s. The overall page will be like this now:

```
<div class="maindiv">
<div><a href="www.facebook.com" class="divlink">div1</a></div>
<div><a href="www.facebook.com" class="divlink">div2</a></div>
<div><a href="www.facebook.com" class="divlink">div3</a></div>
<div><a href="www.google.com" class="divlink">div1</a></div>
<div><a href="www.google.com" class="divlink">div2</a></div>
<div><a href="www.google.com" class="divlink">div3</a></div>
<a class="showmore" onclick="somefunctiontoloadmoreitems()">showmore</a>
</div>
```

That all this functionality is standard means I can't do anything will all this. I can only write some jQuery code to override the `href` of links. Due to my jQuery `onready` event of the document, the `href` of only the first three elements will be overridden. But I want to override the `href` for all the links that will be generated on clicking the showmore button also.

Is there a method to do so?

(This is only one case that I explained to you. I also want to change some more [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets). Is there a method by which I can change all the things?)

Comment: Does the next 3 link will have the same href  value ?

Comment: Are you not allowed to modify the `somefunctiontoloadmoreitems()` function?

Comment: does this really matters??

Comment: yes i cant modify somefunctionloadmoreitems()

Answer (score 2):

Just write it in some other function

```
function somefunctiontoloadmoreitems()
{
  $('.divlink').attr('href','www.facebook.com');
}
```

Tell if this you wanted? I am not sure.

```
function appendvalues(href, classname)
{
   var maindiv = document.getElementById("maindiv").childNodes;
   for(var i=0; i<maindiv.length; i++)
   {
      maindiv[i].setAttribute("href",href);
      maindiv[i].setAttribute("class",classname);
   }

}
```

Try to implement this in your code.

Comment: No this is not what i want. please read the question again. thanks.

Comment: ok you want a parametrized function which append to main div in with passed class and href?

Comment: i want to apply some css to elements. problem is that by ready method i can apply that css only to those elements which are present already not to those which are creating dynamically. i want to add that css to dynamically created elements.

Comment: How you want to give css and class name then?

Answer (score 1):

Edited as per your request, now runs every second for the duration of 10 seconds, after clicking the 'showmore' link.

A more 'elegant' solution would be to stop the interval when the new elements are added, by comparing the count of the elements in the set every cycle run.

```
var modify_links_cycle = 0;
var modify_links_interval = null;

$('.maindiv').on('click', '.showmore', function() {
  clearInterval(modify_links_interval);
  modify_links_interval = setInterval(function() {
    // your modifications to the links
    $('.maindiv .divlink').attr('href', 'http://www.facebook.com');
    // /end
    modify_links_cycle++;
    if (modify_links_cycle === 9) {
      clearInterval(modify_links_interval);
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: this is not a single case i have to override some more settings also.

Comment: so please tell me any method so that all the css and other things of dynamically generated elements will also be change.

Comment: Can you modify somefunctiontoloadmoreitems?

Comment: Does that function load the extra items via an AJAX call?

Comment: i think it dont. it loads only these divs and append them here.

Comment: I modified my solution, please see if it answers your needs, somehow at least.

Comment: i am already doing the same thing buddy. but the problem is that if the net speed of user is slow then what will happen?? :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35221/discussion-between-sachin-kadian-and-timenomad)

Comment: i think i can run it every second for next 10 seconds.. :)

Comment: can you provide me the code so that i can repeat it every second for next 10 seconds?